# Convert text, using sed, awk, grep

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, grep

I am unable to solve a problem. I have a text that contains a email-addresses. I need this file to change the addresses by the pound sign.

For example:

`bla bla bla example{at sign}gmail.com` -> `#######{at sign}#####.###`

Comment: Post a sample input data here.

Comment: Example: "Each message has exactly one header, which is structured into fields. firstemail@gmail.com Each field has a name and a value. secondmail@gmail.com RFC 5322 specifies the precise syntax thirdmail@gmail.com ."

Comment: "Each message has exactly one header, which is structured into fields. ##########@#####.### Each field has a name and a value. ##########@#####.### RFC 5322 specifies the precise syntax #########@#####.### ."

Comment: All this text in one line in the file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed like this:

```
sed -r 's/(^| )[^ @]+@[^ ]+/\1#########@#####.###/g' file
Each message has exactly one header, which is structured into fields. #########@#####.### Each field has a name and a value. #########@#####.### RFC 5322 specifies the precise syntax #########@#####.### .
```

Comment: Does not work with this test `echo "test my@email.com vow" | sed 's/ [^ @]+@[^ ]+/ #########@#####.###/g'` it gives `test my@email.com vow`

Comment: What exactly is "same problem"?

Comment: I get on output "test my@email.com vow" with your solution.

Comment: Works for me, but it removes `not@email`.  My latest `awk` seems to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how would you know if you had an email address. You could assume a pattern such as `/[\.\w]+@[\.\w]+\.\w+/`, but that may include things other than email. Do you want to keep the length, or replace it generically:

- `david@foo.com`           => `#####@###.###`
- `robert.brown@buffy.fu`   => `############@#####.##`

or

- `david@foo.com`          => `#################@##################.###`
- `robert.brown@buffy.fu`  => `#################@##################.###`

The latter could be don with [sed](http://man.cx/sed) using `s/[\.\w]+@[\.\w]+\.\w+/#################@##################.###/`. Note that `sed` varies from system to system -- especially concerning what types of regular expression syntax it can accept. There's at least three different kinds of regular expressions that `sed` could use: Obsolete (or *RE Classic*), Modern (includes some extensions), and Extended (like Perl and Python)

---

#### Tested on Mac OS X - Mavericks

```
sed -E 's/\s*[[:alnum:]\.]+@[[:alnum:]\.]+\.[[:alnum:]]+\s*/######@#####.###/g' rfc-5322.txt
```

I tested this on RFC-5322

Comment: I want to keep the length. About three kinds of regular expressions i hear the first. I just started studying this.

Comment: Keeping the length makes this question much harder. Plus, if your point is to obfuscate information, keeping the length means you might be able to distinguish email addresses even obfuscated. Setting them all to the same length means you completely hide that information.

Comment: My thanks. I am willing to listen and learn another solution. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe i do not understand something, the example above, i get on the withdrawal of the original text. Mmmm?

Comment: To make it some more complicated, look at email regex here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: @user2958448 - As I said, you have to read your sed manpage. Linux's version of sed will take _Extended_ regular expressions. Most BSD systems and Linux will take the _Modern_ regular expression, but you may have to include a particular command line parameter to make this happen. On Mac OS X, the command line parameter is `-E`. I've updated my answer to include a tested version of the regular expression. Note I had to use `[[:alnum:]]` instead of `\w`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` solution

```
echo "test my@email.com vow" | awk  '{split($0,a,"@");f=split(a[1],x," ");for (i=1;i<=(length($f));i++) s=s "#";$f=s}1'
test ############ vow
```

It preserve the length, but may break anything that is not email and has `@`

---

This may work better with multiple email:

```
awk '{gsub(/[^@ ]+@[[:alnum:]]+.[[:alnum:]]+/,"#########")}1' file
```

Comment: Test: input: "my@email.com test my@email.com test my@email.com"; output: "############ test my@email.com test my@email.com".

Comment: I see that, tested a new version

Comment: Nut sure, this works fine for me. What OS are you on?  Here is what I get: `echo "my@email.com my@email.com my@email.com" | awk '{gsub(/[^@ ]+@[[:alnum:]]+.[[:alnum:]]+/,"#########")}1'
######### ######### #########`

Answer (score 0):

An ugly oneliner that will change the file in place:

```
$ cat text
Each message has exactly one header, which is structured into fields. firstemail@gmail.com Each field has a name and a value. secondmail@gmail.com RFC 5322 specifies the precise syntax thirdmail@gmail.com
$ < text egrep -o "\b[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\b"  | sort -u | ( while read b ; do echo "s/$b/$(tr a-z0-9_%+-. \# <<< ${b%@*})@$(tr a-z0-9_%+- \# <<< ${b#*@})/g" ; done ) | xargs -n1 -I{} sed -i,bak {} text
$ cat text
Each message has exactly one header, which is structured into fields. ##########@#####.### Each field has a name and a value. ##########@#####.### RFC 5322 specifies the precise syntax #########@#####.###
```

I took the email regexp from [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html). I also assumed that a dot in the left part of the email should be obfuscated as well: `first.name@gmail.com --> #########@#####.###`